# Generating/Coping KeyPair on USB Token using NodeJS and PKCS11js library

Tags: node.js, cryptography, rsa, pkcs#11, key-pair

I have no problem with doing that in java; however, I can't do the same thing in this library.

In java, I give these attributes (plus my session) to the C_CreateObject method for creating (copying) the public key into the token:

```
CKA_TOKEN
CKA_CLASS
CKA_KEY_TYPE
CKA_MODULUS_BITS
CKA_VERIFY
CKA_MODULUS
CKA_PUBLIC_EXPONENT
CKA_SUBJECT
CKA_ID
CKA_LABEL
```

Is it the same thing in this library?

Comment: Please paste a meaningful code samples for both cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So Insead of C_CreateObject I used C_GenerateKeyPair and it worked.

Comment: If you are looking for CSR generation and Certificate download from modern browsers, refer https://security.stackexchange.com/a/252318/206413